# c# set value at build time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Today I have the following code in asp.net page:

```
<span>V2.0.412</span>
```

Is it possible to set this at build time like this:

```
<span>V2.0.<# DateTime.Now.ToString("%M") #><# DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") #></span>
```

Comment: Have a look at pre-build events. You could maybe do something with that.

Comment: why do you delete all your answers. I was just typing :(

Comment: Because; you can't ask a question in a proper way. You get answers and then you post more details under them making them all invalid. Put all those details into your question and maybe you'll get a straight to-point answer.

Comment: @Adriani6: Admittedly it would be nice to have more context (the project system being used) but other than that, I think it's not a particularly bad question.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I don't think that build/debug stuff is related to project system being used. It is a part of Visual Studio. and so I use VS 2017 v15.6.4

Comment: @realPro: You're asking for something that's related to obtaining information at build time. That's *very* specific to the project system being used, as that determines the build system being used. Something that's feasible in one project system may be infeasible in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can come out of the box would be to use the [`AssemblyVersionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=netframework-4.7), specifying an asterisk for the build/revision (emphasis mine):

> You can specify all the values **or you can accept the default build number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (`*`)**. For example, `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")]` indicates 2 as the major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1 as the revision number. A version number such as `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]` specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision numbers. A version number such as `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")]` specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts the default revision number. **The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is the number of seconds since midnight local time (without taking into account time zone adjustments for daylight saving time), divided by 2.**

So something like:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]
```

You could then extract a `DateTime` value from that, based on the description above. You'd need to change your ASP.NET page to call a utility method to retrieve that `DateTime`, but it would still be the build time.

Admittedly it would be a build-local time rather than a timestamp, but that may be good enough for you.

Note that depending on your project system, you may need to disable compilation determinism in order to get this to work, as per the sample above.

Here's a simple .NET Core app to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var version = typeof(Test).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version;
        Console.WriteLine($"Assembly version: {version}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Build time: {ConvertToDateTime(version)}");
    }

    static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(Version version) =>
        new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
            .AddDays(version.Build)
            .AddSeconds(version.Revision * 2);
}
```

(The epoch of January 1st 2000 is specified in the [old MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx), but not obviously in the new ones.)

And the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>    
</Project>
```

You can even set the `AssemblyVersion` in the csproj instead - although then you need to either set the `AssemblyFileVersion` as well, or disable CS7035. Sample with the same code as the above, but without the `[assembly:AssemblyVersion]` line:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.2.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.2.0.0</FileVersion>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Sample output on my box:

```
Assembly version: 1.2.6676.30244
Build time: 12/04/2018 16:48:08
```

That output stays the same across multiple `dotnet run` calls, until I change a source file, at which point it gets rebuilt, and the build time changes accordingly.

If you don't follow how to get the string you want out of that, here's a self-contained method that does *exactly* that, assuming you've set the assembly version to use `*` appropriately as above:

```
static string GetBuildMonthDay()
{
    var version = typeof(Test).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version;
    var buildDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)
        .AddDays(version.Build)
        .AddSeconds(version.Revision * 2);
    return buildDateTime.ToString("Mdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Currently (at the time of writing, on my machine) that returns "412".

Another alternative would be to generate code as part of the build, but that would move into more customized project territory.

Comment: I do use core project

Comment: @realPro: It's possible that it's feasible after all - I'm still looking. It would be worth stating that in your question though, as you've only got `asp.net` as a tag, which doesn't imply .NET Core at all.

Comment: I think that you have completely misunderstood my question.

Comment: @realPro: In that case, I think you asked it poorly. What I've provided is a way for you to see the build time in your ASP.NET web app. Isn't that what you wanted? Have you tried running the code I've given? For any given build, it will always output the same date/time, which is the time at which it was built.

Comment: Don't see in your answer how you show the build time.

Comment: @realPro: `Console.WriteLine(ConvertToDateTime(version));` That's showing the build time, inferred from the assembly version. I'll edit it to include a message making that absolutely clear.

Comment: I mean where is 412 being set?

Comment: @realPro: I've displayed the complete `DateTime` - but converting that into a month and day is simple, and you already know how to do that. (I'd personally suggest year-month-day, but that's a different matter.) The important thing is that I've shown you how to get "The `DateTime` at which the assembly was built".

Comment: Just look at my question again and see if your solution is sound.

Comment: @realPro: I've looked at your question several times, and yes, I believe my solution is sound. Once you've got the build time as a `DateTime`, you can use `ToString` to obtain the format you want. It's really, really unclear what else you're asking for. You want the build time: I've provided a way of getting that as a `DateTime`. You've already shown code to convert a `DateTime` to the format you want (admittedly using 2 calls to `ToString` instead of one, for no obvious reason). So what's left? What part do you not understand?

Comment: I don't understand how "1.2.*" gets converted to 12/04/2018 16:48:08. Puzzling...

Comment: @realPro: I've now added a method that returns "412" at the moment. Running the same build tomorrow would return "412". Rebuilding tomorrow, it would return "413". But if you don't understand what happens with the "1.2.*" you probably need to read the quoted text and follow the documentation link.

Comment: @realPro: Have you had a chance to reread the answer? Does it now make more sense, or do you still believe I've completely misunderstood the question?

Comment: Thanks, it will be more easy for me just to set the number by hand: 2.0.412

Comment: @realPro: How is that easier? You'll need to change it every time you do a build. Very error-prone. I've given you the method to convert the assembly, a sample project file... it's *really, really* simple at this stage. It should take you less than 5 minutes to integrate it into your project. Do you *really* think it's better to have to change a source file manually for every build?